# The minimum number of comparisons required to find the minimum and the maximum of 100 numbers

Tags: time-complexity

```
(A) 147.1 to 148.1
(B) 145.1 to 146.1
(C) 140 to 146
(D) 140 to 148
```

If n is odd: 3*(n-1)/2 
If n is even: 3n/2 -2

> Here n = 100,

3n/2 - 2 = 3*100/2 - 2 = 148
how is it 147.1 to 148.1 ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the formatting of this question but how can the number of comparisons required by a non-integer?

Comment: http://geeksquiz.com/gate-gate-cs-2014-set-1-question-49/

Comment: Is the given answer wrong ?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm just wondering at the mindset that allows `0.1` of a comparison to exist - what is `0.1` of a comparison?

Comment: Even I'm wondering the same.

Comment: If we postulate that the given ranges are being specified with exclusive start and end points then 147.1 - 148.1 is the only given range that contains the number 148. But still, a very oddly worded question.

Comment: Same explanation I'd, earlier.